# count all numbers in range having a specific digit

Tags: java, count, integer

I want to count how many numbers have digit number 4 in a range of numbers

e.g 1-100  count all numbers having digit number

i.e 4,14,24,34,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,54,64,74,84 and 94 total 19 numbers

I am having problems with counting number of integers with digit 4 in them please help!!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        while (true) {
             Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
             int num1 = input.nextInt();
             int num2 = input.nextInt();

            if (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0) {
                 for (int num = num1; num <= num2; num++) {
                     while (num != 0) {
                        int i = num % 10;
                        if (i == 4) {
                            count++;
                            break;
                        }
                        num = num / 10;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(count);
           }
           else
               break;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly is the problem now? I guess that your program is not behaving the way you want it to, but could you please give more context?

Comment: And your question is...

Comment: I would convert to a String and then use `contains`

Comment: `num = num / 10;` affects `num ` from `for (int num = num1;  ... )`. Create separate temporary variable on which you will be doing your operations.

Comment: thanks its counting but cant cant count the numbers having 4 as second digit like it coiunts 4,14,24,34,44,54,64,74,84,94 but not 40,41,42,43,45,46,47,48,49 thanks

Comment: @Unknownuser Description of problem is important info which should be placed in the question itself. Use [edit] option to place it there instead of putting in comment section hidden among other comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//a few changes were needed into your code.. here is the solution...

```
public class MaxOccurance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int count = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 = input.nextInt();
        int num2 = input.nextInt(), temp;

        if (num1 != 0 || num2 != 0) {
            for (int num = num1; num <= num2; num++) {
                temp = num;
                while (temp != 0) {
                    int i = temp % 10;
                    if (i == 4) {
                        count++;
                        // break;
                    }
                    temp = temp / 10;
                }
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if a number contains a specific digit or not, here is a trick you can use :

- Convert both number and digit to String and use `String::contains` (Simple)

Here is a piece of code you can use If you are using Java 8 :

```
int number = 4, min = 0, max = 100;
String numberToString = String.valueOf(number);

long count = IntStream.rangeClosed(min, max)   //Range of numbers between min and max
        .filter(n -> String.valueOf(n).contains(numberToString)) // Use the filter
        .count();// Then count the result

System.out.println(count); // 19
```

Comment: me too @ScaryWombat, maybe it is not well explained

Comment: Suggested edit: as `number` never changes do `String.valueOf(number)` only once

Comment: I wasn't down-voter but I suspect two reasons: (1) OP is learning basics so showing him solution involving more advanced knowledge (lambdas so inner/local classses) may not be useful for him/her (but that reason shouldn't be valid for downvote since SO doesn't exist only for OP but for all with same/similar problem), (2) it doesn't explain problem which OP is having.

Comment: This is correct @Pshemo The solution of the OP is a little complicated, for that I suggest this solution, It is readable at least

Comment: Nitpicking: `//Range of numbers between min and max` "between" suggest that both numbers are treated same way (either both are included or excluded), but here `min` will belong to that range, but `max` will not. Maybe it is worth using `rangeClosed` to respect OP way which includes `max`.